# Copy Reviews from website_id 1 to website_id 2

Tags: sql

This is more of an SQL question. I have very little knowledge in MySQL

In the `review_store` table, there are two columns: `review_id` and `store_id`

If I had to replace 1 with 2 I would do this:

```
UPDATE review_store 
SET store_id = '2' 
WHERE store_id = '1'
```

What would be the SQL query if I wanted to copy/duplicate all values of 1 in `store_id` to a new row with a value of 2

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it was more of an SQL question than a Magento so [I asked on the regular Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274490/sql-query-copy-all-rows-with-store-id-1/31274546#31274546) as well, here's the answer

```
INSERT INTO review_store
SELECT review_id, '2' as Store_id
FROM review_store
WHERE Store_id = '1'
```

I also had to apply the same logic to the `review_entity_summary` table, which has 6 columns: `primary_id`, `entity_pk_value`, `entity_type`, `reviews_count`, `rating_summary` and `store_id`. The first columns is PRIMARY so I had to skip it so it'll automatically create a new value. SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO `review_entity_summary`(`entity_pk_value`,`entity_type`,`reviews_count`,`rating_summary`,`store_id`)
SELECT `entity_pk_value`,`entity_type`,`reviews_count`,`rating_summary`,'2'
FROM `review_entity_summary`
WHERE `store_id` = '1'
```

Then in order to have the STARS displayed I had to go to `catalog > reviews and ratings > manage ratings`, click on the rating and add the new store.

I hope this can help others with the same goal.

Best,

Answer (score 0):

Try this also,

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable SELECT * FROM review_store WHERE store_id = 1;

UPDATE tmptable SET store_id = 2 WHERE store_id = 1;

INSERT INTO review_store SELECT * FROM tmptable WHERE store_id = 2
```

Comment: Will this work given primary key values?